# i18n in cake - how to use language shortcut like en instead of eng

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have my app ready for translation but unfortunately I developed it using 'en', 'de' and 'pl' language shortcuts instead of 'eng', 'ger' and 'pol'. Now I see that when I do `Configure::write('Config.language','pl')` cake doesn't want to read translations from `App/Locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/default.po` - but it works with `pol` for example. The problem is that all my links, interniationalized files and so on are using 'en','de','pl' - I can't just change it to 'eng', 'pol' and so on... How I can force cake to use my configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 letter language code for `Config.language` configuration value and your urls. But name your locale folders using the corresponding 3 letter code. So for your  language codes 'en', 'de', 'pl' the folders would be `Locale/eng`, `Locale/deu`, `Locale/pol` respectively. Cake will properly look in the corresponding folder for translation files.